# How do I refactor my code to make it more concise without using SASS?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple signup form using this HTML. Am I separating my code properly here or is there some code that I could remove/change?

The form looks good visually, but when I styled it with CSS I noticed a lot of stuff I had to repeat.

```
<body>
    <form action="#" class="form">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
      <h1>Join our community of developers from all over the world</h1>
      <div class="form-box">
        <div class="email">
          <label for="email">email</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="password">
          <label for="password">password</label>
          <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="password2">
          <label for="password2">confirm password</label>
          <input
            id="password2"
            type="password"
            placeholder="confirm password"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up" />
      <p>Already have an account</p>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Here is my CSS. Is there a better way to style each form input and label without having to seperately display flex each input like I did below?

```
.form {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1391ff, #0145ff);
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 120px 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #0000008f;
}

.img-overlay::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/06/13/18/mosaic-2721424_960_720.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -20%); */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.18;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.589);
}

.form h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

#email,
#email::placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231, 0.8);
}

.password {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

#password,
#password::placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231, 0.8);
}

.password2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

#password2,
#password2::placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231, 0.8);
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0145ff;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.473);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

I feel like I'm repeating a lot of code in the CSS, but I'm not sure if I am doing it properly even though my code creates the sign up form and everything looks good aesthetically.

Comment: Code Review is the best Q&A site on the Stack Exchange's network to ask questions about code improving etc... Visit it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

#### Utility Class

> **1** style in `css` reused **many** times in `html`

- create utility class in `css`

```css
.text-orange {
    color: orange
}
```

- apply utility class name in `html`

```html
<div class="text-orange">Lorem</div>
<p class="text-orange">Lorem</p>
```

---

> **1** group of styles in `css` reused **many** times in `html`

- create utility class in `css`

```css
.flex-col-center-start {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

- apply utility class name in `html`

```html
<div class="flex-col-center-start">box1</div>
<div class="flex-col-center-start">box2</div>
```

---

#### This is the same way you use **[Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/)**, **[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)** or **[Materialize](https://materializecss.com/)**

- so you can reduce a bunch of code by building your own library
- **But you will end up adding a bunch of class name to `html` as well**
- Note that the **Tailwind** is **very similar to** the way we described above, the difference is that, **Tailwind already define these granular styles for you**. So you can use Tailwind to reduce your code as well.

---

#### Use utility class without adding any class name to `html`

- If you still want to reuse code in this way while not adding any utility name to `html`, you can try sass -> `@extend` function, you can check out this example [here](https://github.com/GeekEast/floating-layout-sass-hotelBT/blob/master/scss/pages/_contact.scss)

Answer (score 0):

You could add some classes to your elements and put common styles there. Elements having an `id` can have `class` or even multiple classes without any problem.

Comment: so like class="form__input email" , then class="form__input passwordl" etc.? Are you able to copy my codepen and edit the tags you are referring to? Or is that the only thing I could do to make my code more concise?

Comment: Smart `class` strategy will most likely be enough. You could also play with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), but I don't think that's necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your css will get leaner over time - don't sweat it. Your methods will emerge with practice.

Some very quick wins:

**1) don't re-declare values unnecessarily**

```
.button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 14px 14px;

}

.button:hover {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 14px 14px; 
}
```

I've only chosen three as an example - but the hover state will retain width, border-radius and padding. Only declare here what you want to ***change***.

**2) Group together rules where it makes sense to**

```
.email,
.password,
.password2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Personally, I would avoid creating utility classes. Your markup can become cluttered:

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-a-million-other-classes-that-have-to-be-removed-in-your-markup-if-your-client-changes-their-mind">Click</a>
```

Lastly, what I would recommend is reconsidering SASS - it makes for more more organised (and re-usable) code. What you could do in that case is go:

```
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

And then any time you want to use it:

```
.email {
  @extend .flex-center;
}
```

Declare the utility class once, apply it once, take it off once, globally.

Comment: ah thanks for the suggestions. I didn't know about the hover state retaining those values and I realized I could group the inputs together. As far as Sass, this was just a short project  I made for fun and was just testing out my current knowledge